# External coordinates breaks alignment of groupplots

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72804/18982) showed how to make overlay drawings with nodes defined in previous plots using `TikZ`. However, that solution (ie. adding `cell picture=if necessary` to the axis) does not work with `groupplots`.

If I do not use the option, I get the same problem that was solved by the answer linked to above, and even worse results for the second plot:

[image]

Adding the option to the `\nextgroupplot` commands (which are equivalent the axis statements) solves part of the problem (the arrows point to the nodes) but it breaks alignment of the plots:

[image]

**Question**: how can I make overlay drawings using nodes that have been defined in previous plots by `groupplots`?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary[pgfplots.groupplots]

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1},ymin=0,ymax=3]
      \nextgroupplot[cell picture=if necessary] \addplot {1};
      \node [fill,red,circle,draw,label={above:A}] (a) at (axis cs:-4,2) {};
      \nextgroupplot[cell picture=if necessary] \addplot {2};
      \node [fill,blue,circle,draw,label={above:B}] (b) at (axis cs:4,1) {};
    \end{groupplot}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{A \texttt{groupplots} plot}
  \end{figure}

  This arrow should point to A
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[red,->] (0,0) -- (a);
  and this arrow should point to B
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[red,->] (0,0) -- (b);

\end{document}
```

Comment: it is the lag of interaction between the `pgfplots` layer and `groupplots`. Instead, you should try the "manual" alignment (there is an example of what `groupplots` do in its section) and see if the problem persists. Perhaps that could help?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this has a duplicate somewhere on this site...

Comment: @zeroth, that was really helpful. I used your comment for a self-provided answer below. Hope that's OK.

Comment: @jja That is PERFECT! Very good! Hope to see you again. :)

Comment: Actually, your MWE worked fine for me it just took a couple of runs.  In fact, it works wihtout `[cell pictuire=if necessary]`.

Comment: I mean, a lot can change in 10 years :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comment by @zeroth, I was able to put together a manually aligned set of plots. I'm pretty sure the code can be improved (particularly the placement of the figure caption) and I'm not at all sure what problems this might have (with, for instance, `externalize`), but this solves my problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  every axis/.append style={ymin=0,ymax=3,cell picture=if necessary}
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,remember picture]
    \begin{axis}[name=left column]
      \addplot {1};
      \node [fill,red,circle,draw,label={above:A}] (a) at (axis cs:-4,2) {};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[at={(left column.below south west)},yshift=-1cm,anchor=north west]
      \addplot {2.5};
      \node [fill,red,circle,draw,label={above:C}] (c) at (axis cs:4,1.5) {};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \hspace{0.15cm}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,remember picture]
    \begin{axis}[name=right column]
      \addplot {2};
      \node [fill,red,circle,draw,label={above:B}] (b) at (axis cs:4,1) {};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[at={(right column.below south west)},yshift=-1cm,anchor=north west]
      \addplot {1.5};
      \node [fill,red,circle,draw,label={above:D}] (d) at (axis cs:-4,2.5) {};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{A fake \texttt{groupplots} plot}
  \end{figure}

  This arrow should point to A
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[red,->] (0,0) -- (a);
  ; this arrow should point to B
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[red,->] (0,0) -- (b);
  ; this arrow should point to C
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[red,->] (0,0) -- (c);
  ; and this to D
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[red,->] (0,0) -- (d);

\end{document}
```