# Drawing between plots with groupplots pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, coordinates, groupplots, drawing

I am trying to create a zoom effect for the plot on the left. I make a box in it and I want to draw lines from two corners of the rectangle going to the plot on the right. I thought it might be straightforward with `\coordinate` but `pgfplots` seems to forget the coordinate passing to another plot. Is there a possibility to make this effect using `groupplots` ?

[image]

Here is a MWE of my plots.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1,ylabels at=edge left,},
            xlabel=$X_\text{Cr}$,ylabel=$\mu$,
            ]
            
            \nextgroupplot[xmax=1.1,xmin=-0.1,ymax=30000,ymin=-23000]
            \draw (0,-21000) rectangle (0.2,10000);
            \coordinate (A) at (0,-21000);
            \coordinate (B) at (0.2,10000);
            
            \nextgroupplot[xmax=0.2,xmin=0,ymax=10100,ymin=-23000]
            
            \addplot coordinates {(0,-20000) (0.1,-10000) (0.18,9000)};
            
        \end{groupplot}
        \draw (A) -- (group c2r1.north west);
        \draw (B) -- (group c2r1.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this help here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103151/external-coordinates-breaks-alignment-of-groupplots ?

Comment: Not in the way intended, but I figured what was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by trying a different approach. It seems that the `scale=` option given to `tikzpicture` was messing with the coordinates and thus pointing the lines to nowhere. Since I always need to reduce the size of the picture, I used `small` option (see `pgfplots` documentation).

[image]

Here the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1,ylabels at=edge left,},
            xlabel=$X_\text{Cr}$,ylabel=$\mu$,small,/tikz/font=\footnotesize,
            ]
            
            \nextgroupplot[xmax=1.1,xmin=-0.1,ymax=30000,ymin=-23000]
            \draw (0,-21000) rectangle (0.2,10000);
            \coordinate (A) at (0,-21000);
            \coordinate (B) at (0.2,10000);
            
            \nextgroupplot[xmax=0.2,xmin=0,ymax=10100,ymin=-23000]
            
            \addplot coordinates {(0,-20000) (0.1,-10000) (0.18,9000)};
            
        \end{groupplot}
        \draw (A) -- (group c2r1.south west);
        \draw (B) -- (group c2r1.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```